# SQL Server subqueries in CASE THEN with multiple JOINS

Tags: sql-server

I've searched high and low for an answer but I'm not finding one...

I'm trying to run a subquery inside a `CASE THEN` statement based on qualifier, that goes something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN cbpotm.DOLCheck LIKE '%<%'
        THEN
        (
            SELECT
                ...
            FROM #AnotherTempTable AS CB
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
            WHERE CONDITION AND CONDITION
            AND CONDITION IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
            AND CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(tflr.DateKey AS VARCHAR), 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(tflr.DateKey AS VARCHAR), 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(tflr.DateKey AS VARCHAR), 7, 2) AS DATE) BETWEEN CB.SomeDate AND CB.SomeOtherDate
            GROUP BY FIELD, FIELD
        )
        END
FROM    
#TempTable cbpotm
```

Apparently I'm missing the mark because I'm not allowed to have more than one `JOIN` inside the `CASE THEN` without introducing the statement with an `EXISTS` clause.
I'm not trying to compare the statement to anything so I can't see why I should only use a single field to match against?
I also don't see why I should use `EXISTS` because I'm not trying to perform validation...

Comment: The predicate of the `THEN` in your `CASE` expression must return a single scalar value.  That subquery in there looks very suspicious.  You might want to update your question with sample data and expected output to show us what you want to do here.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*, not a statement. It produces a *single scalar value* (per row). Is that what your subquery is trying to generate? I.e. if you remove the `CASE` entirely and just have this as a subquery in the `SELECT` clause, does it work?

Comment: It appears that the temp tables in the outer and sub query should be joined based on your qualifier condition and in that case "case when" is not needed i guess.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM    
#TempTable cbpotm
outer apply
(
            SELECT *
            FROM #AnotherTempTable AS CB
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
            WHERE CONDITION AND CONDITION
            AND CONDITION IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
            AND CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(tflr.DateKey AS VARCHAR), 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(tflr.DateKey AS VARCHAR), 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(tflr.DateKey AS VARCHAR), 7, 2) AS DATE) BETWEEN CB.SomeDate AND CB.SomeOtherDate
            AND cbpotm.DOLCheck LIKE '%<%'
            GROUP BY FIELD, FIELD

) tmp
```

Comment: I would have gone this route but I do a date comparison which is why I look for a '<' or '>' in an 'if' statement so that I can run a particular query based on the return result.